# Map Toolbar always shows in liteMode

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I show a map in a `RecyclerView` with `LiteMode` and everything was working how I expected until last night. I believe my phone finally got the new Google Play Services `7.3` update and when I started my app this morning every instance of the LiteMode map has the little open in google maps app icon in the bottom right.

[image]

In my `onBindViewHolder` of my RecyclerView I try to disable the toolbar like so

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor,int position) {
        if(viewHolder.mGoogleMap != null){
            viewHolder.mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(incident.getPosition()));
            viewHolder.mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            viewHolder.mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
            viewHolder.mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                }
            });
            CameraPosition p = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(incident.getPosition()).zoom(15).build();

            viewHolder.mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(p));
        }

    }
```

and in my ViewHolder I try to disable it after the map loads like this

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
    map = (MapView)v.findViewById(R.id.mapImageView);
        if(map != null){
            map.onCreate(null);
            map.onResume();
            map.getMapAsync(this);
        }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if(this.context != null) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.context);
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
        Cursor c = getCursorAtPosition(getAdapterPosition());
        if(c != null){
            Incident i = new Incident(c);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(i.getPosition()));

            CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(i.getPosition()).zoom(15).build();

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
            }

        }

    }
```

I dont think there is anything wrong with my logic as far as recycling and what not so how do I disable the toolbar?

**Edit**

As a matter of fact clicking on the icon does not even work correctly, it opens the google maps app but center at position 0,0

Comment: Just wonder how did you include Google Play Service 7.3? I think the newest is 7.0 right? Link: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: @ztan i did not include it, I said my phone updated to it

Comment: But the newest on in Play Store is 7.0 right? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Comment: @ztan no the new google play services is 7.3 http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/04/17/google-play-services-7-3-adds-a-new-ui-for-trusted-places-and-finally-makes-the-persistent-android-wear-notification-dismissible-apk-download/

Comment: This is probably a 7.3 issue then, because `setMapToolbarEnabled(false)` should help you to disable the tool bar. You might create an issue in the Android public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 2):

Someone submitted this issue to Google and they have accepted it and are looking into it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7947). I would recommend that everyone experiencing this problem *Star* [Issue 7947](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7947) on Google's issue tracker to get prompt updates, because there seem to be no known workarounds for this bug.

Version 7.3.29 of Google Play Services seems to have introduced a couple of bugs with maps :/

Comment: +1. Hopefully Google will fix this and other bugs with Google Play Services before all my users' phones update to v7.3.29

Comment: yeah some weird stuff started happening when mine updated, like I now have to manually set `setMyLocationDisabled` to false in onDestroy or else location will stay on when I leave the map